# How should I import list of results with scientific numbers so they can be used for further calculation?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, data

I have a file, `listOfResults.txt`, consisting of many rows of which the following is an example:

```
0.074,0.004,1000,0.0,3.29561020691e-09,0.001,3.27917377617e-09
```

What is a good choice for `Export` parameters when importing numbers like those shown, including the scientific type?

First three numbers in each row are parameters, the remaining numbers are results.

I would like to import it to a variable `rawData` as a table of numbers or test (I don't know what to choose). Then I want to convert the scientific forms such as `2.Te+6` to a form understood by Mathematica.

I also want to write code for a function `listOfResults` such that

```
listOfResults[0.074, 0.004, 1000]
```

returns

> ```
> {3.29561*10^9, 0.001, 3.27917*10^9}
> ```

Problems:

Import-data does not allow me use the scientific conversion:

```
rawData = StringReplace[rawData, {"e+" :> "*^", "e-" :> "*^-"}]
```

Import-string allows use the above code, but it is problematic to instruct the function `listOfResults` to the call

```
listOfResults[a, b, c]
```

work correctly with the parameters `a, b, c` — the `c` parameter works for 1.0*10^3 but not for 1*10^3.

I have tried

```
rawData = Import[file, "Data"]

rawData = StringReplace[rawData, {"e+" :> "*^", "e-" :> "*^-"}]

rawData = ImportString[rawData, "CSV"];

(listOfResults[rawData[[#, 1]], rawData[[#, 2]], rawData[[#, 3]]] = 
   {{rawData[[#, 4]]}, Drop[rawData[[#]], 4]}) &
 /@ 
   Range[Length[rawData]]
```

Comment: `Import[ file,  "CSV" ]`  ?

Comment: There may be something strange going on with this string because when I copy it into Mathematica is does not look like it does here on Stack Exchange (double commas, among other things) but when corrected it works with `ImportString[str, "CSV"]` (i.e. you don't have to do replacements and such.) As LouisB says, `Import[file, "CSV"]` should work.

Comment: I have simplified it but the original .nb file adjusted now based on LouisB's comment with the result file is here:    
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B5l2icboZhU7s1PZ_NiSdDUbWlRYWW6t/view?usp=sharing   unfortunately still not working, the last input does not provide the results